# Golang strconv.ParseFloat fails to parse the string correctly when using 32 for bitSize parameter

Tags: go

Why the converted float64 variable has `1.590000033378601` as value?
`1.59` seems small enough to be fitted into 32 bits:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := `1.59`
    float, err := strconv.ParseFloat(str, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T -> %+v\n", float, float)
}
```

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/s8uUCsteao)

Comment: Please google "what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic" and keep a copy for reference.

Comment: `7/23` or `sqrt(2)` also "seem" small enough to fit into 32 bit floats, but neither of those is going to give you a nice even result either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is precision issue of 32bit variable. This is not an issue of Go. See following URLs.

[IEEE 754 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

[Single-precision floating-point format - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

You will understand what happen with 1.59 in this C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  float f = 1.59;
  if (f == 1.59) {
    puts("float: equal!");
  } else {
    puts("float: not equal!");
  }

  double d = 1.59;
  if (d == 1.59) {
    puts("double: equal!");
  } else {
    puts("double: not equal!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/WobYbU

1.590000033378601 is 1.59 in 32bit variables. So you can use the value with cast to float32. i.e. float32(1.590000033378601)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := `1.59`
    f64, err := strconv.ParseFloat(str, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err: ", err)
    }
    f32 := float32(f64)
    fmt.Printf("%T -> %+v\n", f32, f32)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ml4O8CtjOK)

## UPDATE

On Most of computer, floating point value is stored as following elements.

- Sign (zero or one)
- Significand (Coefficient)
- Exponent

For example, representations 0.75 is `+1.1 x 2^-1`

`+` is Sign, `.1` is Significand, `-1` is Exponent. This is stored like below on 32bit memory space.

```
Sign                                 Significand
+-+               +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      Exponent
```

For example, `0.75` is stored like below

```
0-01111110-10000000000000000000000

     +- Significand
     |
+ 1[.1] x 2 ^ -1
|         |    |
+- Sign   |    +- Exponent
          |
          +------ Base
```

> + 1.1 x 2^-1 = 1 x 2^0 + 1 x 2^-1 x 2^-1 = 0.75

Since floating point value is represented as above, it is different between the mathematical value and the computer's value. This is precision issue.

Comment: Still it's not clear to me the reason, maybe you can elaborate which part of wikipedia page can explain this behavior?

Comment: Thanks @mattn for through explanation. I have one question:
`float64(6301000)*float64(0.035)` results in `220535.00000000003` but I expect `220535`, if I use `float32(X)` on final result it gives the correct value, but since the float64 uses more bytes shouldn't it be safe to use it in arithmetic calculations?

Comment: yes, this will occur even though using 64bit. but precision is better than 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal number `1.59` looks short, but that's only because we are using the **decimal number system**.

When the computer tries to represent the same number in **binary scientific notation** (`a * 2^b`) it requires a lot more fractional digits: `1.1001011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110001 * 2^0`.

If you round this value to 32 bits, store it in a variable of type `float32` and then print as decimal, you get `1.59`, but storing the same rounded value in a `float64` variable and printing as decimal, you get `1.590000033378601`.

Function `strconv.ParseFloat` returns float64, but since you have specified 32 bits of precision, you are supposed to cast the value to float32 prior to using.